# How to get the selection item in list view using pyqt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Here is my sample code. When I click the index item in list view, I am getting the selection item,it's working fine.But I want to get the selected item using up and down arrows. Can anyone please help me. Thank you in advance.

Given below is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui
class mtable(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.auto_search1 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.auto_search_vbox1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.auto_search1)
        self.auto_search_vbox1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        hbox1=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.le_search1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.se_btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Search")
        self.searchBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Close")
        self.searchBtn.clicked.connect(self.auto_search1.close)
        self.se_btn1.clicked.connect(self.filterClicked1)
        hbox1.addWidget(self.le_search1)
        hbox1.addWidget(self.se_btn1)
        hbox1.addWidget(self.searchBtn)
        self.auto_search_vbox1.addLayout(hbox1)
        self.total_list1 =[]
        self.list1 = QtGui.QListView()
        self.list1.clicked.connect(self.on_treeView_clicked)
        self.model1 = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.list1)
        self.y =['one','two', 'three']
        for i in self.y:
            self.total_list1.append(i)
        for code in  self.total_list1:
            item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(code)
            self.model1.appendRow(item1)
        self.list1.setModel(self.model1)
        self.auto_search_vbox1.addWidget(self.list1)
        self.auto_search1.show()
        self.auto_search1.resize(1000,500)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_treeView_clicked(self, index):
        itms = self.list1.selectedIndexes()
        for data in itms:
            print index.data().toString()
            self.le_search1.setText(index.data().toString())
            self.filterClicked1()
    def filterClicked1(self):
        print "searching logic"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tb = mtable()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here I need to select the green highlighted item using arrow keys without clicking the item

[image]

Comment: I have tested your code and it works correctly, for example I clicked initially on the "two", and then I pressed the up arrow button and the selection moves to "one", if you press the down arrow button you select "two" again , and if I press down again, select "three", do not you have that behavior?

Comment: but i am not getting sir

Comment: One thing is to select an item and another is to click, I think you are confusing both events. When you click, it is selected, but with the arrows you select but do not click, so in the latter case, the clicked signal will not be emitted.

Comment: When you say: *i am not getting two*, you mean that "two" is not shown in the QLineEdit?

Comment: What do you mean by selecting? Do you mean that it shows up in the QLineEdit?

Comment: yes exactly sir ..

Comment: You are confusing concepts, according to your code you are only showing the text of the item clicked

Comment: sir i don't know to how to set the item text in line edit  according to up and down arrows so i wrote this logic but this is not correct logic that why i am asking you..

Comment: this code is working fine but i want to set the highlighted  text in line edit without pressing/clicking  the items in list view..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `currentChanged` signal of the `selectionModel()` of the QListView:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.search_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Search")
        self.close_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Close")
        self.listview = QtGui.QListView()
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.listview)
        for e in ('one', 'two', 'three'):
            model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(e))
        self.listview.setModel(model)

        # signals connections
        self.listview.selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(self.on_currentChanged)

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.selectFirstItem)

        # layout
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        vlay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        hlay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        hlay.addWidget(self.search_button)
        hlay.addWidget(self.close_button)
        vlay.addLayout(hlay)
        vlay.addWidget(self.listview)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    def selectFirstItem(self):
        self.listview.setFocus()
        ix = self.listview.model().index(0, 0)
        self.listview.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(ix, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_currentChanged(self, current):
        self.lineedit.setText(current.data())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```